# Save CSV values into variables in shell

Tags: shell, csv, awk, sh

I need to read each lines of a CSV file and save values into variables.

Exemple of my CSV file with multiple lines :

```
 value1;value2;value3
 value4;value5;value6
```

I have this :

```
 for enreg in `cat ../files/inputs/file.csv`
   do
     INFO1= `echo $enreg | awk -F ';' '{ print $1}'`
     INFO2= `echo $enreg | awk -F ';' '{ print $2}'`
     INFO3= `echo $enreg | awk -F ';' '{ print $2}'`
     echo "INFO1= $INFO1"
     echo "INFO2= $INFO2"
     echo "INFO3= $INFO3"
     echo "$INFO3;$INFO2;$INFO1" >> ../files/output/files.csv
  done
```

I have the following result in console:

```
 INFO1= value1
 value4
 INFO2= value2
 value5
 INFO3= value3
 value6
```

But I need this to write in the second CSV file:

```
 INFO1= value1
 INFO2= value2
 INFO3= value3
 INFO1= value4
 INFO2= value5
 INFO3= value6
```

Thanks for your help and have a nice day.

**_______________________________________________________________________________**

**UPDATE**

My CSVmatricule.csv is :

```
value1;value2;value3 
value4;value5;value6
```

My CSVmatricule.ks is :

```
while IFS=";" read -r f1 f2 f3 
  do 
    echo "INFO1=$f1" 
    echo "INFO2=$f2" 
    echo "INFO3=$f3"
  done < ../files/inputs/CSVmatricule.csv
```

My console result :

```
INFO1=value1 
INFO2=value2 
INFO3=value3
```

The result of `cat -vet ../files/inputs/CSVmatricule.csv` :

```
value1;value2;value3$
value4;value5;value6
```

Why the second line of the CSV isn't take in count ??

Comment: `I need to read each lines of a CSV file and save values into variables.` - that is extremely unlikely. More likely this is an example of the XY problem, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378. If you tell us what you are trying to do we can tell you how to solve your problem rather than telling you how to implement this almost certainly bad attempted solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about just using an `awk` command for this?

```
$ awk -F";" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "INFO%d=%s\n", i, $i}' file
INFO1=value1
INFO2=value2
INFO3=value3
INFO1=value4
INFO2=value5
INFO3=value6
```

This loops through the `;`-separated fields and prints them together with `INFO` + number.

If the number of fields is fixed, you can also use a `while` loop:

```
while IFS=";" read -r f1 f2 f3
do
  echo "INFO1=$f1"
  echo "INFO2=$f2"
  echo "INFO3=$f3"
done < file
```

This is the way to loop through the file sequentially, instead of your `for ... in cat ...`. This way, every loop in the `while` reads a line. Also, by giving more than one argument to `read`, each `;`-separated field is assigned to its corresponding variable. 1st to `$f1`, 2nd to `$f2` and the rest to `$f3`.

---

If you need to store these values as variables, just say: `source <( command )`.

Comment: Hi fedorqui and ty for your reply.
The first solution work perfectly but with the second one, the result is
    INFO1=value1
    INFO2=value2
    INFO3=value3
But it doesn't work with the second line.

Comment: @Florian_L it works to me: what do you get if you say `while IFS=";" read f1 f2 f3; do echo "INFO1=$f1"; echo "INFO2=$f2"; echo "INFO3=$f3"; done < file` ?

Comment: I get :

`INFO1=value1
INFO2=value2
INFO3=value3`

Comment: @Florian_L I cannot say more. Maybe your file contains weird characters? Check with `cat -vet file`. With the file you showed, it works to me.

Comment: @Florian_L what do you mean with "it doesn't work with the second line"? You mean the writing to the output/files.csv ?

Comment: The second line `value4;value5;value6` is not printed in console. The loop stop after the first line of the CSV file.

Comment: @Florian_L as I said before, this I cannot know why it is happening if you don't provide more details.

Comment: My CSVmatricule.csv is : `value1;value2;value3      value4;value5;value6`
My CSVmatricule.ks is : `while IFS=";" read -r f1 f2 f3 do echo "INFO1=$f1" echo "INFO2=$f2" echo "INFO3=$f3" done < ../files/inputs/CSVmatricule.csv` My console result : `INFO1=value1   INFO2=value2    INFO3=value3`

Comment: @Florian_L better update your question since it is not clear what is new lines and what spaces.

Comment: Thank you for your help I am new on stack.

Comment: @Florian_L weird, it works perfectly fine to me with the given script and input. Try to `cat -vet ../files/inputs/CSVmatricule.csv` to see if any weird characters are confusing your script.

Comment: @Florian_L also, why not just going for the `awk` command? It works : )

Comment: yes you are right butI am a little bit confused why the while loop didn't work for me

Comment: I found the solution : if there is no empty line at the end of the CSV file, it doesn't work but if there is an empty line at the end of the CSV, it printed `INFO1=value1  INFO2=value2  INFO3=value3  INFO1=value4  INFO2=value5  INFO3=value6`

Comment: Ty so much for your time. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `IFS` variable so that `read` command splits on ';':

```
export IFS=";"
cat ../files/inputs/file.csv | while read INFO1 INFO2 INFO3
 do
   echo "INFO1= $INFO1"
   echo "INFO2= $INFO2"
   echo "INFO3= $INFO3"
   echo "$INFO3;$INFO2;$INFO1" >> ../files/output/files.csv
done
```

Comment: this is exactly what my solution is doing by saying `while IFS=";" ...`

Comment: Thank you for your reply robert but same as fedorqui solution, just `INFO1=value1  INFO2=value2  INFO3=value3` are printed on console.